# A word(s) describing a person with control/power over an important aspect of others lives. They abuse that power to harm others and personal gain

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, american-english, vocabulary

I am in need of a word(s) or term(s)for a person who willingly, openly, and unapologetically abuses the power or influence they have over other peoples lives,more precisely; people who have control or strong influence over integral aspects of another's livelihood such as ability to take away your income, housing, scholarship, promotion, license, freedom, ecetera.. aspect of another's life. Some people that usually have this power would be: landlord, boss, teacher, professor,Judge, police officer,etcetera...The one abusing their "power" does so either for personal gain or simply because,"they can"
Some close associations pertaining to the type of word im seeking would be narcissist, sociopath,and psychopath.

I am seeking this because i seem so be having an issue where multiple of these "***insert word here*** have manifested themselves into every aspect of my life and have either already successfully destroyed that part of my life or they are currently working towards destroying it. Thank you for taking the time to help me out to whomever decides to.

## EDIT

4/5/2024 tyrant is a close fit, however, the word im looking for needs the ability to be used in a legal argument and not stick out life a sore thumb so to speak.

## ***An example of what I mean***

When referring to illicit subtances in legal circumstances, instead of using the scientific or medical speak such as **depressants**, **stimulants**,or **psychostimulants.**
In court, the substances are going to be referred to as **narcotics** followed by the accepted street name of the drug.
**TYRANT** would be like **stimulants** in the example.

Thanks in advance and I would like to apologize  for going so long without replying to the answers given.

Comment: Not sure all the duplicate suggestions are valid duplicates, but tyrant seems to have both the control aspect and negative connotation needed.